# Excel VBA Array Function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to understand arrays more thoroughly. Can someone please explain to me why this does not compile:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim Names As String
    Names = Array("Brian", "Steve", "Andrea")
    Debug.Print Names(2) 'Compile error: Expected array
End Sub
```

and why this compiles but does not run:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim Names() As String
    Names = Array("Brian", "Steve", "Andrea") 'Run-time error '13': Type mismatch
    Debug.Print Names(2)
End Sub
```

but this works, even though I didn't add `()` (unless declaring it as type `Variant` makes it an array?):

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim Names As Variant
    Names = Array("Brian", "Steve", "Andrea")
    Debug.Print Names(2)
End Sub
```

and so does this, as expected:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim Names() As Variant
    Names = Array("Brian", "Steve", "Andrea")
    Debug.Print Names(2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Array is type of Variant. Please, check [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262675(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: A `Variant` can very well hold a pointer to an array. That makes `Variant()` pretty much redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `Array` function returns Variant data type containing an array. Check [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262675(v=vs.60).aspx).

> **Note**   A `Variant` that is not declared as an array can still contain an
>   array. A Variant variable can contain an array of any type, except
>   fixed-length strings and user-defined types. Although a Variant
>   containing an array is conceptually different from an array whose
>   elements are of type Variant, the array elements are accessed in the
>   same way.

Comment: Your update answered my question with the note. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome. If it fixes your issue, please, accept my answer as a solution.

Comment: I certainly will, but it said I had to wait 7 minutes. :) +1 for now.

Comment: OK. I'm not in rush ;)